# Nested sortables as drag targets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a drag-and-drop outline tool.  It uses jQueryUI's `.sortable()` in a nested fasion to build a tree of elements.  I also have a palette of items using `.draggable()` that can be dragged into the outline at any given level.

Dropping a new item into the topmost level of the tree works fine.  But when I drop one into the 2nd level down, the item gets duplicated.  When I drop one into the 3rd level, the item gets duplicated twice!  I've boiled the problem down to its essence here: http://jsfiddle.net/curtisfarnham/TGAqW/

How can I prevent items from getting duplicated when dropped into the lower levels of the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jquery ui 1.8 serie, event bubbling.

See updated jsFiddle using jquery ui 1.9.1

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TGAqW/3/

Comment: Thanks!!!  I'd seen 1.9.1 was out, but I read about the breaking changes and I wasn't sure I wanted to deal with a compatibility layer.  Looks like I'll have to delve into it after all.